# Rollback Transaction on Errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions

I have a large generated script. It has multiple batches (`GO` statements). The first line is `BEGIN TRAN`

If any errors occur during execution, either raised myself using `RAISERROR`, or raised by SQL Server, I want to rollback the transaction. I want the script to continue executing until the very end, then rollback, not abort execution as soon as any error occurs.

Checking `@@error <> 0` at the end of the script doesn't seem to be sufficient, because if the last statement in the script succeeds, @@error will be 0, even though previous statements failed.

I can't declare a `@rollback BIT` at the very beginning because the script is segmented into multiple batches, and so the variable is out of scope.

I understand that `RAISERROR` doesn't mean my transaction will be rolled back.

Any suggestions on the best way to implement this in a SQL 2000 compatible manner?

Comment: Didn't you get error: `The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.`?

Comment: No, I do not...the transaction commits at the end even if I raiseerror much earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) to pass 'out-of-band' information, and read it later using [`CONTEXT_INFO()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx). If an error occurs, set the context info to a value which you check just before commit.

This answers your question of how to do it, but I really have to express my doubts about *why* do it in the first place. For one many errors will abort the transaction *anyway* so you may blindly proceed believing that is safe to continue and rollback only to discover that there is nothing to rollback and all your erroneous script after the exception has *committed*. Second, for the exceptions than do not abort the transaction, is still very questionable to do any work only to roll it back. Your request is so out of the beaten path than I must wonder if you really understand all the implications of what you're doing.

Comment: I want the whole script to run so that the user can get a list of all errors that are in the script that they need to correct....otherwise they would need to correct one error at a time. I'm certainly open to other suggestions on the matter.

Comment: Thanks. The script has several EXEC('...') statements too though. Will PARSEONLY work with that?

Comment: I think SET CONTEXT_INFO was introduced in SQL 2005

Comment: @Clint: SET CONTEXT_INFO is in SQL 2000: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259199%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Jeff: no, parse only will not handle EXEC or sp_executesql calls.

Answer (score 1):

A common technique is to create a temporary table and use boilerplate code at the end of each batch

```
begin tran
go

create table #errors (errorid int not null)
go

select 1/ 0

declare @error int
set @error = @@error
if @error <> 0 insert into #errors values (@error)  
go

select 1/ 1

declare @error int
set @error = @@error
if @error <> 0 insert into #errors values (@error)    
go

if exists (select * from #errors)
begin
    print 'rolling back transaction'
    select * from #errors
    rollback tran
end
else
begin
    print 'commit transaction'
    commit tran
end
go

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#errors') is not null
    drop table #errors
go
```